# How to recycle ColdFusion web services after modifying underlying web service signature

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

ColdFusion seems to cache its initial request to a web service. When modifying the web service's signature (e.g, adding a parameter to the web service method) it seems that ColdFusion has no idea how to call that web service until the "ColdFusion 2016 Application Server" Windows service is restarted. This complicates development as it affects all ColdFusion websites during that restart period effectively clearing all sessions.

The context of the execution of these web services are through the `CreateObject` method.

```
Application.MyWebServiceVariable = CreateObject("webservice", "PATH");
```

In the past other have mentioned using the `refreshwsdl` argument, as such.

```
oWsdlArgs = structNew();
oWsdlArgs.refreshwsdl="yes";
Application.MyWebServiceVariable = CreateObject("webservice", "PATH", oWsdlArgs );
```

Unfortunately this does not resolve the underlying issue where the actual Windows service must be restarted in order for ColdFusion to refresh its internal cache of that web service method signature.

I can also confirm that simply restarting the ColdFusion application using `ApplicationStop()` does not work.

Is there a way to recycle this internal cache of the web service signature so that developers don't need to restart the Windows service?

**Additional Notes**

- Apparent in ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016
- Web services are SOAP-based hosted on IIS
- Web services' logic are within a DLL

Comment: Are your web services written in ColdFusion or are you calling some other (3rd party) web services from ColdFusion? If the latter, then that would explain why `refreshwsdl` does not work. That is specifically for web services written in ColdFusion.

Comment: @Miguel-F No, the web services are written in C#, compiled to a DLL and exposed through IIS where the WSDL is derived directly from the DLL.

Comment: Have run into same issue multiple times but unfortunately do not recall what, if anything, I found to clear it. I believe CF or something underneath creates java class files that correspond to the webservice objects. Might be able to clear those directly if you can find them..

Comment: When you use `CreateObject("webservice", ...)` I guess you stored the webservice data in `CFAdmin`. Can you provide the address of the WSDL directly in the call to CreateObject?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That's what I currently do when using `CreateObject`; the second parameter is the URL to the web service's WSDL.

Comment: @MiguelF - Where did you read it's only for CF web services? I always thought it was for any WS. I ran a quick test with the WCF test client and and it did refresh under CF 2016,0,10,314028.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling these webservices using createObject and/or cfinvoke, then as you have seen, CF caches the definitions. The easiest way I have found to refresh these definitions without a CF service restart is if you have access to the Coldfusion Administrator.

CF Admin -> Data & Services -> Web Services

Under there you should see an entry for each wsdl that CF has cached, with a button to use to force it to update.

Comment: Oddly enough the web services I create programmatically using `CreateObject` do not appear in that list on ColdFusion Administrator. Perhaps there's a setting to enable that in the server.xml?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a setting - the wsdl URLs have always 'just appeared' in every version of CF Admin I've used. Any chance you're running multiple CF instances on Enterprise and looking at the wrong instance admin?

Comment: No we only have the 2016 version. Interesting that it always just appears for you, I'll have to dig deeper into why it wouldn't for me. I had thought this "Web Services" page in ColdFusion Administrator was for web services hosted by ColdFusion and not a caching repository.